# Where, in the routing table, the peer information is stored?

Tags: p2p, bittorrent, dht, torrent, kademlia

**I mean, node ID's on k-bucket's "have" the IP and port number**

- How RPC get_peers query is answered?
- Where the peer information about a torrent infohash is stored?
- Where the metadata come from?

I was reading about on http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html, but that's no clear for me

Comment: Have you also read *Peter Maymounkov, David Mazieres, "Kademlia: A Peer-to-peer Information System Based on the XOR Metric"*?

Comment: Yes, but the routing table does possess only relative informations to the nodes, right? Maybe I have interpreted something wrong, but was what understood

Comment: Oh yeah, sure, this stuff is not stored in the routing table, it's in other data structures. How they are managed is up to the implementation. The BEP is not a step-by-step plan how to write an implementation.

Comment: Great, but, supose that a node found the informations about a torrent infohash (nodeID, IP, UDP port number), what it does after this? How the found node knows the peer informations in order to answer the RPC get_peers? I'm sorry if my questions looks fool, I'm  beginner.

Comment: It was put there by an announce message